# ffmpeg error: Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): No such file or directory

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I have the following files in the Convert_video_to_HLS folder on my Desktop:

- input
- output
- script.sh
- video.key
- video.key.info

The command I'm running is:

```
bash ./Desktop/Convert_video_to_HLS/script.sh ./Desktop/Convert_video_to_HLS/input ./Desktop/Convert_video_to_HLS/video.key.info ./Desktop/Convert_video_to_HLS/video.key ./Desktop/Convert_video_to_HLS/output
```

The contents of script.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR=$1
DIR_KEY_INFO=$2
DIR_KEY=$3
OUTPUT=$4
echo $DIR
# List all mp4 files on folder
MP4_DIRS=$(find $DIR -type f | grep -E "\.mp4$")
mkdir -p $OUTPUT
for addr in $MP4_DIRS
do
FILE=$(basename $addr .mp4)
mkdir -p $OUTPUT/$FILE
cp $DIR_KEY $OUTPUT/$FILE/
ffmpeg -i $addr -codec: copy -start_number 0 -hls_time 20 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_key_info_file $DIR_KEY_INFO -f hls $OUTPUT/$FILE/$FILE.m3u8
done
```

The error message i get is:

```
[hls @ 0x7fd654012400] Opening './Desktop/Convert_video_to_HLS/video.key.info' for reading
[hls muxer @ 0x7fd65401c600] error opening key info file ./Desktop/Convert_video_to_HLS/video.key.info
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): No such file or directory
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

Help appreciated. FYI I'm new to bash script and following a tutorial so a breakdown would be appreciated.

**Update**:
I have placed the files in my root directory and run the following command, and it seems to work.

```
bash ./script.sh ./input ./video.key.info ./video.key ./output
```

Therefore, for some reason, the folder directory is not being referenced correctly.

Comment: Did you get the ffmpeg command to work before attempting to integrate it into your Bash script? Also, see shellcheck.net.

Comment: Shellcheck.net is not throwing up any errors. 
the ffmpeg command is not working, however, I have found this one which works, but I'm not sure which variables to change around:

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -s 640x360 -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls index.m3u8`